# Authenticating the application in embedded systems - Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there any way to authenticate the application to use the Google Drive API without a native browser in an embedded system?

I'm looking for a solution to the user accepts and put your password and username using the OAuth2.0 without browser interactions... Is it possible?

My applications is build in Java Code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two legged auth would solve your problem . Watch closely this question stackoverflow.com/questions/12605705/does-google-drive-api-support-2-legged-oauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presently trying to do just this and I don't think it is possible because:

To authenticate in embedded device you need to use this process:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices

the problem with this, is that it only accept limited range of scopes like:

--https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
which works OK

but when you try with scope like:
--https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.*

you get invalid_scope.

If you find a solution please let me know, I have the same problem my device is embedded, has no screen, and is not available with remote desktop of the like.

thanks for any feed back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [OAuth 2 device flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices) which is designed for cases where a browser isn't available on the device. It allows the user to complete the login & authorization on a separate, more capable device (phone/tablet/laptop) where a browser is available.